# Merging and working in parallel with Git

Tags: git

I have several branches of a git project, with the differences primarily being in configuration files and blobs. I'd like to keep these projects mostly merged and in synch, since developments on one branch need to occur on the other parallel branches as well, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Most git guides and the like I've seen don't really talk about it, and I'm not sure what the best approach is for this sort of problem.

Cherrypicking may be an option, but of course it means someone working on one of those branches loses pretty much the entire history of the various changes. If there's a way to say "cherrypick everything in this huge project except the files defined in this file" or something, that might still work though. It still seems wrong, somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have one main branch with several sets of configuration files. If you only intend to keep one set of such files in each branch at any point in time, you can maintain one main branch (with all the common files), and commit those config files as a separate commit in each of the other branches. Whenever the main branch gets updated, you will need to rebase the other branches against it, so as to apply their config commits on top of the latest changes.

```
main-------update 
      \
       \--branch1 for env1 (commited config for env1)
```

becomes

```
main---update-- 
               \
                \-- rebased branch1 for env1 (commited config for env1)
```

or even

```
main---update------------------------------merged with branch1-- 
               \                        /                       \
                \-some work in branch1-/                         \-rebased branch1 for env1 (commited config for env1)
```

Comment: Hmm... actually, would the rebasing even be needed here? just having a seperate branch for each project, with the main branch not having any config files at all seems like it would work. It means I would still have to cherry pick changes back in if stuff is developed on one of the branches, and it would be hard going developing on master without configs but... I think this gets me closer, at least.

Comment: When you rebase in this fashion, you are asking the subsidiary branches to follow the main branch at all times except for their own config files. Since only the config files can be a source of conflict and they are always applied last, rebase will almost always work without any need to cherry pick (you should simply merge your features as normal). This is solely for the purpose of keeping config files in separate branches. If possible I would just keep all the config files in main with proper classification.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Since the config files are the only change, the rebase applies them on top of whatever code is being "merged" in, even if master has its own config files, while as a regular merge would overwrite them. This is a great answer for the config files, at least, but isn't rebasing a one step process, meaning I'd lose the history of the various blobs, since rebasing means things get pruned?

Comment: That only happens if you squash the commits otherwise you should be able to keep everything with possibly different timestamps. Admittedly I only do this with config files (when there are just a handful of them)

Comment: Ah, with your edit, that fixes the final problem of history even if it did - by merging it back in, it maintains the history somewhere (even if it makes it a bit more confusing, at least it's in main somewhere), but because both branches are rebasing it doesn't effect them at all. Okay, having checked this with the project, I think this works! Thanks!

Comment: I would need to warn you that work on the subsidiary branches can no longer be pushed normally (without the use of --force) if the config commit is to be stored on the remote branch, for the reason that it should not appear anywhere on main (when you attempt to merge). If eventually you decide that this is too much trouble, you should consider putting all the config in one place grouped by the designated branchnames, or adopt a more elaborate scheme as suggested by Hamish.

Answer (score 1):

I would split your project in two:

- core project (all the shared code)
- configuration / blob assets.

You core project should have a minimual number of branches - only those you need for development.

Your configuration repo contains the rest.

On a 'per project' basis, you can merge sources with a tool like [Piston](http://piston.rubyforge.org/), [submodules](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html) or [puppet](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/puppet) (depending on the structure of your project).

With this setup you can keep the number of core branches down to a minimum as required for development, testing and deployment. It doesn't matter if your configuration branches diverge because you never have to merge them, and cherry-picking changes between them is far simpler as you don't have to figure out if the change is core or configuration.

It allows you to have a per-app configuration that fixes to a specific tag or commit in the core project, so moving between versions for testing, etc, should be much easier too.

Comment: These seems like it might give me what I need - I'll have to try it out before accepting it though. I had considered making a separate project for the configs, but I didn't want to lose the historical relations between the configs and the project, since they'll almost always be update together. If there's a way to set it up so the config project commits are hooked to the main project commits, though, that should work.

Answer (score 1):

What you're really looking for is a good branching model. You should take a look at [this](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).  It is essentially a nice way to manage a lot of related branches. It does require discipline, but in the long run, it is worth it.

Ofcourse, I'm assuming your configuration files and blobs are not massive (Gigabytes). If they are, you probably want to use sub modules to manage them in a separate repository as @Hamish suggests.

Comment: I'm not really sure how this particular answer is relevant to the solution, I'll be honest. I read through the link, but I'm not seeing how its supposed to be helpful. That is in fact the model I already use - except I have two 'masters', two 'release versions', and that's where the difficulty lies.